# Why color is not getting applied to my bootstrap html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started with my bootsrap navbar. Below is how my basic code look likes:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 landing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-value="home" href="#">Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-value="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-value="hobbies" href="#">Hobbies</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-value="education" href="#">Education</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background:#f4f4f4;
}

.navbar{
    background:#F97300;
}
.nav-link , .navbar-brand{
    color: #f4f4f4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-link{
    margin-right: 1em !important;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    color: #f97300;

}
.navbar-collapse{
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

I am unable to figure it out why those colors are not getting applied.
For example `.nav-link` has `color:#f4f4f4` (whitish) which does not get applied. All I see is black. Same is the case with `.nav-link:hover {color:#f97300}`, which is orange. But on hover over link to keeps color black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being overridden by selector [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) you can see when inspecting the output in the developer tools.

You could add `!important` to your values to override that like `color: #f4f4f4 !important`, or provide the same selector specificity that bootstrap's css is using to apply it. Like `.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link { color: red }`

Answer (score 0):

Your custom css might be getting overwritten by the default bootstrap css that's why it is not woring

Comment: Congrats on your first answer! Could you clarify how and why is the default bootstrap css overwriting his styles and what to do about it?